# How to create a menu without a bar?

Tags: android, menu

I have an application without an appbar. Now I want to put 3 Buttons into a menu. I have seen the option to create a toolbar and then add the items programmaticlly. But first I would prefer not to have a bar but just the menu. 
I know that that isn´t really important because I can make the bar transparent.
And Second I really don´t want to add the items programmatically. (But defigned in xml.) Is this possible, are there better ways and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "By the menu" you mean, the overflow menu that exists in the app bar then you can not just the add the menu that way. The app bar or toolbar has to be there to contain that overflow menu. But for giving that sort of effect as you also mentioned you can have the toolbar transparent or you can look into the PopUpMenu, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html,
this way you can hide your app bar and can give a separate button which will call PopUpMenu, its going to give you same overflow menu effect. 
Regarding your 2nd requirement of putting menu in xml, if i am getting it correct you can have your menu defined like this,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:title="@string/phone"
            android:icon="@drawable/phone"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/computer"
            android:title="@string/computer"
            android:icon="@drawable/computer"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! But now my problem is that when I put the code you posted in my activity layout the menu and item tags won´t be recognised. Could you plese tell me how I can implement  this into a toolbar or pop up menu?

Comment: didn't get you mate, try posting your code what you have tried.

Comment: would you mind up voting answer, if it worked for you :)

Answer (score -1):

You need your CSS anymets revised.

Please consider this codings:

```
style {template.css}
```

I think you'll find those are the exact answer.

Comment: CSS with Android? How?